# Implementing Nested Navigators to Conceal Tabs for Different Screens using Navio in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am currently utilizing the [Navio](https://github.com/kanzitelli/rn-navio) library within my React Native project to manage navigation. My objective is to employ nested navigators in order to selectively hide tabs for specific screens. I am seeking guidance on achieving this functionality utilizing the navio.build() function provided by the library.

Problem:
I have integrated the Navio library into my React Native project to handle navigation. The library offers the navio.build() function, which appears to be a key component for constructing navigation structures. However, I am uncertain about the correct approach to implement nested navigators utilizing this function, with the specific goal of concealing certain tabs on specific screens.

Desired Outcome:

- Utilize the navio.build() function effectively to set up nested
  navigators.
- Hide specific tabs for designated screens within the
  navigation hierarchy.

I am seeking guidance on the appropriate modifications to the navio.build() function in order to achieve nested navigators and hide tabs on specific screens.

Any insights, code examples, or documentation references related to implementing nested navigators using the Navio library would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and assistance!